# footable pagination not working on dynamic data Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, pagination, footable

I am trying to use footable in my rails application.But I am unable to implement pagination with my dynamic table data.

Here is my code

```
<table class="footable table table-stripped" data-page-size="10" data-filter=#filter>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Organization Name</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <%@organizations.each do |org|%>
                <tr class="gradeX">
                    <td><%=org.name%></td>
                    <td><%=org.type%></td>
                </tr>
                <%end%>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5">
                        <ul class="pagination pull-right">
                            <%=paginate @organizations%>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
alert(); //testing
$('.footable').footable();

});

</script>
```

But It shows only 10 records though it contains upto 45 in table(shows maximum of 10 records even changing data-page-size).

Help me If anyone finds this issue,Thaks In advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still having this issue but I've stumbled upon this question so I figured I'd answer it.

The reason this is occurring is because you're calling Footable's `Paging Component` on records that you have already paginated via a Rails gem, indicated by your use of

```
...
<ul class="pagination pull-right">
  <%=paginate @organizations%>
</ul>
...
```

So Footable is only being served 10 records by your Rails app and then trying to paginate those. Essentially you're "double paginating" one set of data.

In `Footable V3` the syntax is now:

**Calling it via HTML Data Attributes**

```
<table class="footable table table-stripped" ... data-paging="true" data-paging-size="15" ... >
```

**Calling it via JS**

```
$('.footable').footable({
                "paging": {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "limit": 10
                  }
               });
```

Refer to [Footable Paging Docs](http://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/components/paging.html#limit) for more info.

So essentially, choose either **Rails Paginate** or **Footable Paging** but not both. Hope this helps.